# Extract Numbers After String Which Includes Quotes, Brackets, Braces in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

There are numbers directly after the following string:

`"balances":[{"balance":`

Stuck with escaping the quotes and anything else. Nothing I tried worked unfortunately.

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:"balances":[{"balance":)\K\d+")`

Comment: `\K` doesn't do what you think it does; at least not in Javascript.

Comment: This was the example I was looking at

https://regex101.com/r/Kecmbr/1

Comment: Cool, now click "Javascript" on the left side.

Comment: Ok, I removed the \K part. Now just need to figure out the escaping quotes and other characters. I tried `""` and `"&char(34)&"` with no luck

Comment: I don't know what that means. Provide a regex101 with your attempt and actual data from your spreadsheet.

Comment: In a sheet, put this in A1:


`"balances":[{"balance":896785`


In any other cell put:


`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:"balances":[{"balance":)\K\d+")`


Where the final output we're trying to get is:


`896785`

Comment: A Chrome-specific solution is [`"(?<="balances":\[{"balance":)\d+"`](https://regex101.com/r/abO8If/1)

Comment: @newbiew8572: for the example given and looking at the desired output, wouldn't something like =regexextract(A1, "\d+") work for you?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @JPV Unfortunately not, there is a lot more data surrounding my example. If someone googles  "Extract numbers after string" + any sort of mention of escaping special characters, would be nice if this example came up.

Comment: We're close, the following:
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:""balances"":\[{""balance"":)\d+")`
successfully extracts and outputs:
`"balances":[{"balance":896785` instead of just the desired `896785`

Comment: Final answer:
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:""balances"":\[{""balance"":)(\d+)")`
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that

- To input a double quote in a double quoted string literal in Google Sheets you need to double it
- If you need to extract a part of a regex match with `REGEXEXTRACT` you need to use a **capturing group** to enclose that part with a pair of unescaped parentheses
- If you do not need to quantify a sequence of patterns or use alternation there is no need to wrap that pattern part with a non-capturing group, just remove it.
- Google Sheets regex engine is RE2 that does not support most Perl "extra" features, like `\G`, `\K`, `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and what not. If you want to test a regex online that should be RE2 compatible test it at http://regex101.com using `Golang` regex flavor.

Use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"""balances"":\[{""balance"":(\d+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sNTfs2/1).

Answer (score 0):

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:""balances"":\[{""balance"":)(\d+)")`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.